# Restrict user to login with single userid/Password on multiple browser or computer

Tags: asp.net

I have to implement one functionality in my website, I never worked on this kind of situation so i am confused how can i implement this.

Requirement:- I want to restrict user to login with single userid/Password on multiple computer or browser. Just like any bank website where user can not login with single user credential on multiple browser or computer.

Please help me. I am using ASP.NET.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164507/allow-one-session-only-at-a-time  Not ASP.NET, but it fits the concept exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yah, use isonline or same kind of filed in database and when use login make it true, if filed value is true when login send message that your are already login from other computer.

Comment: Suppose user close his browser or he leave his session after login and after some time session will expire then how we handle that database flag?

Comment: you have to handle it in globle.asmx in session_out