# How can I validate current user session id with database stored session ids?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have found that Code Igniter has already ci_sessions table which stores users session ids in it. I understand the main purpose of that table. Just I want to clarify how I can validate with ci_session table data with my current user login session id?

Basically , I am trying to do User login one place at a time. Multiple login's to be prevented. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't do that with session ID's since logging in from another location would create a new session ID at that new location.

Store the userID to the session then check it on login.

```
$this->db->where('userId',$userId);
$result = $this->db->get('ci_session');
if($result->num_rows() > 0)
{
    //log out old user, throw error, whatever
} else {
    //continue with login
}
```

Comment: i did with session id for each user login and cross check the session id for the user and force / destroy it

Comment: the sessionId isn't specific to a particular user and it's unique, not exactly sure what you did but glad you got it sorted.

Comment: i am generating the session id for each user and checking while login

Answer (score 0):

By storing the user id in the session data and adding it as a column to the sessions table, you can remove all sessions of that user id on login before the session data is created. This will invalidate any session of the same user. For further explanation on how to do this, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564433/89211