# How to check whether the user is already logged in on different ip/locations

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to check whether the same user is logged in more than one locations over different IP and if a user already logged in then the previous session will be destroyed.

Is there any solution on YII framework?

Currently I am trying to develop this project on YII framework.

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow one session only at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164507/allow-one-session-only-at-a-time)

Comment: check out, this will be help you - http://yii.at/BUgobo and http://yii.at/lcFDr2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

- add a "last_session_ip" column to your userdata table
- when a user logs in, update its last_session_ip field with its
  current  ip
- create a function like `loginauth()` which will compare the current ip
  with db value . if not same destroy the session

this is not a proper solution but this can put you on right track.

Comment: but this doesn't imply that the user is logged in on that ip address , i beleive so ....

Comment: User can use static ip from there service provider. In this case also multiple login happens

Comment: this is just a logic .

Answer (score 0):

Without any storage you can't do this. you should use database for logging the log in history and when user log in again, compare the user IP and other things you want by new user which signed in and do what ever you want to that user.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this API if you want to store client's locations (Ex: Country, City, ...):
[checkgeoip.com](https://checkgeoip.com)